# How to run an function in xml from viewmodel? Android, Kotlin, Databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I'm trying to run a view animation. When I type text in TextInputEditText the view should disappear but I get an error:

**"/app/build/generated/source/kapt/debug/.../MixerSimpleFragmentBindingImpl.java:1416: error: missing return statement }"**.

**BindingAdapters.kt**

```
@BindingAdapter("textChangedListener")
fun onTextChanged(et: EditText, callback: () -> Unit) {
   et.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
      override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
         callback.invoke()
      }

      override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
      override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}
    })
}
```

**SimpleMixerViewModel.kt**

```
class SimpleMixerViewModel : ViewModel() {
   val isVisible: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData(false)
   ....

   fun click() {
        isVisible.value = true
    }

   fun typing(){
        isVisible.value = false
    }
}
```

**mixer_simple_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>
<variable name="simpleMixerViewModel" type="....SimpleMixerViewModel"/>
</data>
....
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      app:textChangedListener="@{()-> simpleMixerViewModel.typing()}"
      />

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
      android:onClick="@{() -> simpleMixerViewModel.click()}"
      />

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    isVisible="@{simpleMixerViewModel.isVisible}">
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

fun click() works.

fun typing() not works

Answer (score 0):

You should use an interface instead of kotlin lamda in your bindingAdapter.